# If $u\in C^\infty_c(U)$ then $u\in L^p(U)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to prove an inequality in $W^{k,p}(U)$ and I am attempting to prove take sequences in $C^\infty_c(U)$ converging to $u\in W^{k,p}(U)$. A main part of my proof relies on the fact that if some sequence $(u_k)_{k=1}^\infty\subset C^\infty_c(U)$ converges to $u\in W^{k,p}(U)$, then it follows that such a sequence converges to $u$ in $L^p(U)$. Does this necessarily hold?

I believe it is. If some function $v\in C^\infty_c(U)$ then it has compact support inside $U$, it is continuous and then bounded. That would then mean that $||u||_{L^p(U)}$ is bounded correct? Moreover $||D^\alpha u||_{L^p(U)}$ is finite for any $\alpha$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\|u\|_{L^p(U)}\leq C \|u\|_{W^{m,p}(U)}$ for some $C>0$.

Comment: This inequality implies that if $u\in W^{m,p}(U)$ then $u\in L^p(U)$ right? How about if $u\in C^\infty_c(U)$? Is it then in $L^p(U)$?